# CRM Plugin Serverconnection missing reference

Tags: crm

I am using the sample code from the crm samples that come with the sdk and this error keeps showing. How to i add this serverconnection missing reference? I am at a loss to find where it is to add it? or what namespace it belongs to?

[image]

Comment: Is this happening in a console application? Check the target framework. If target framework is Client Profile, even if after adding all required references you will get this type of errors.

Comment: Double check that the target .NET framework is 4.5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a connection code for crm online I hope you serve:

```
ClientCredentials Credentials = new ClientCredentials();
Credentials.UserName.UserName = UserName;
Credentials.UserName.Password = Password;
Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
Uri OrganizationUri = new Uri(Crmserverurl);
Uri HomeRealmUri = null;
using (OrganizationServiceProxy serviceProxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(OrganizationUri, HomeRealmUri, Credentials, null))
{
    crmSvc = (IOrganizationService)serviceProxy;
}
```